# Possible to convince Jedi to autocomplete lists?

Tags: python, jedi, python-jedi

I'm getting a huge amount of utility out of exposing an object to tree at the command line to a python program. For example:

```
myprog.py  obj1.obj2.method
```

Let me execute obj1.obj2.method(), and

```
myprog.py  obj1.<TAB>
myprog.py  obj1.obj2<TAB>
```

lets me see what available. Awesome! However, I can't convince jedi to return autocomplete results lists (or dictionaries). I was hoping something hacky this this might work for short lists:

```
class X:
    pass

x = X()
x2 = X()
x2.y = 456
x.z = [x2]

# Want to get x.z[0].y in the results
prefix = "x.z[0]."

import jedi
# Tell jedi about list elements?
script = jedi.Interpreter(prefix, [{"x.z[0].z": x.z[0].z}])

for c in script.completions():
    print c
sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 2):

If anything, this should work:

```
>>> script = jedi.Interpreter(prefix, [{"x": x}])
>>> script.completions()
```

However at the moment it returns an empty list. I think it would be worth adding an issue to the Jedi issue tracker, since this is something that can definitely be done.

If I remember the Jedi code correctly, Jedi tries to not call `getattr` in certain cases (like class lookup), but this could easily be changed, since it's:

1. Not consistent anyway, Jedi would call `getattr` on objects that are not complicated, like `x.y`.
2. The standard library autocompletion also calls `getattr`.

If you want that, just add an issue to the Jedi issue tracker.